# Flask seems to launch 2 instances of python

Tags: python, flask

I have several Flask applications, but they all seem to launch 2 instances of Python. I have no idea why.

Edit: I have googled for Flask and multiple instances of Python, etc, but not one of my searches led me to the 'already answered question' here. I find my question much more to the point than: "Why does running the Flask dev server runs itself twice?" Huh? What is the Flask dev server? Does it have anything to do with Python running twice?

Comment: What does this mean? What are you counting as "launching an instance of Python"? How do you tell? How are you serving the applications?

Comment: I can see that in Activity Monitor (OS X) or by ps -ef|grep py. Also, in one of my programs I use: if __name__ == '__main__':
 print "starting Flask server"
 app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)  This prints 'starting Flask server' twice!

Comment: I do not understand the down vote. This must be a very common problem, but after quite some searching I still could not find a decent answer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It happens because you run your Flask applications in debug mode:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Debug mode automatically reloads the source files when they change. This is implemented so that Flask (actually, [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org), a library used by Flask) spawns another Python interpreter, which monitors the source files and restarts the other interpreter that is running your Flask app.

If you set `debug=False`, you should get only one instance of Python per Flask app.